# Does CAS support OAuth Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant?

Tags: oauth, cas, jasig

After some rudimentary testing I've gotten CAS to work with the Authorization Code Grant. This seems to be the only grant mentioned in [the documentation](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth+server+support). Does CAS support other grants outlined in the OAuth2.0 draft 2-31 section 4.3? What are the service endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the OAuth server support for CAS and so far, it only supports the authorization code grant which matches pretty well with the CAS webflow...

Comment: Does CAS support any other grant type other than Authorization Grant?